# Is it possible to have a regular list with <select> tag in html?

Tags: html, css, list, select, drop-down-menu

I have seen that  and  tag always create a drop down list. However, I am trying to have a regular list, the one that can be created by `<ul><li></li></ul>`. 
I tried this:

```
    <select>
    <ul> 
    <option><li>a </li></option>
    <option><li>b</li></option>
    <option><li>b</li></option>
    </ul>
    </select>
```

However, I see no results. Can someone make a suggestion?

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a multiline select would do what you what. Add the `size` attribute to the `select`. See the snippet below:

```css
ul {
list-style:none;
}
```

```html
Default select style: <br>
   <select>
    <option value="a">option a</option>
    <option value="b">option b</option>
    <option value="c">option c</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <hr>


  Multiline select style:<br>
  <select size="3">
    <option value="a">option a</option>
    <option value="b">option b</option>
    <option value="c">option c</option>
    </select>
  <br/>
  <hr>


  Using ul/li + Radio options:
  <ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="optionset" value="a">option a</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="optionset" value="b">option b</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="optionset" value="c">option c</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! ive been trying to solve this for ages and it was just one word!

Answer (score 2):

**Save the code in the html file and test the links in real time**

```html
<div class="comboBox" id="combo">
 <select class="selec" id="select" onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
  <option value=""><ol><li>Choose site<li><ol/></option>
 <option value="https://www.google.com/"><ol><li>google<li><ol/></option>
 <option value="https://www.facebook.com"><ol><li>FACEBOOK<li><ol/></option>
 <option value="https://www.youtube.com/"><ol><li>YOUTUBE<li><ol/></option>
 </select>
</div>
```